# Lightweight Java socket library

Tags: java, sockets, apache-mina, netty

I've used Mina and Netty, but now I'm in the market for a lightweight library that may also be used in Android. I prefer Nio or AsyncIo over standard io implementations.

**Update 1**

The lack of responses really makes me think I should write my own library. Right now I'm using raw NIO and its not a lot of fun.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html ?

Comment: @arunkumar raw nio is very hard to use, definitely not simple, really a royal PITA all around. That's why people put libraries like Mina on top of it.

Comment: I agree, i use mina quite often.

Comment: I'm surprised that there's not more activity on this question; is everyone actually writing low-level Nio code?

Comment: I wrote such a library on NIO, maybe it will be interesting after 9 years)) https://github.com/tix320/sonder

Comment: @Tix Thanks for the reply, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems to be dead on arrival, I'll answer it by saying my custom IO library will be the best.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using some pieces from Jetty as [suggested in this email.](http://osdir.com/ml/java.jetty.general/2003-01/msg00022.html) I really like Jetty because it's small, self contained, and you can use some or all of it flexibly.

Comment: Is the socket library in Jetty externalized from the server itself?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, there is no one size fits all async library. Netty and Mina might be the closest to such a thing, but most projects may still have to contain some pure NIO/ASYNCIO customized solutions.

I maintain you are on the right track. The more experience you have with low-level NIO/ASYNCIO the more you will appreciate and be able to get the most out of the somewhat-less-low-level Netty.

Comment: Yeah dont get me wrong i love mina, its an excellent library but I'm more or less looking for something closer to NIO without making you feel the pain.

Comment: Netty is lower level than Mina, and encapsulates most of the learning curve of NIO.